# Generate Excel using PHPExcel fail because the file format or file extension is not valid

Tags: php, cakephp, phpexcel

I'm using CakePHP and PHPExcel to generate excel files,
i can generate files and save them in the server and they work, but when i use `$objWriter->save('php://output');` and open the downloaded file i get `file cannot open file because the file format or file extension is not valid`.

i even used `ob_start();` at the beginning of the script and `ob_end_clean();` before the saving but i still get the same error

here is my code(this code is from the examples of PHPExcel, i just added the ob_start and ob_end_clear):

```
<?php
ob_start();
App::import('Vendor', 'PHPExcel');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
    die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
        ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
        ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
        ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
        ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
        ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
        ->setCategory("Test result file");


// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
        ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
        ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
        ->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');

// Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A4', 'Miscellaneous glyphs')
        ->setCellValue('A5', 'éàèùâêîôûëïüÿäöüç');

// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');


// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); // always modified
header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
ob_end_clean();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

and here is the generated file: https://mega.co.nz/#!RZFURbTA!DaGVv1NzRZn3VGq0FSf57nQTKiB--4sq2udj2HkTq2U

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in a text editor, and you'll find a newline character as the first character of your file.... despite your use of ob_end_clean() your script is injecting this newline into the PHP output stream before the save (perhaps a blank line before your opening `<?php`

Comment: i checked that ..i even wrote `<?php ob_start();`

Comment: You may have checked it, I'm only reporting the evidence, and surmising where the blank line is coming from.... but that blank line at the top of the file is coming from somewhere

Comment: Is there anyway i can find out where it is comming from?

Comment: Enable full error reporting, and your headers should generate a warning message (which will also be injected into the output stream) that should be readable in the generated xls file when opened in a text editor.... that warning message should be a "headers already sent" message, which should identify the script name and line number where the initial newline output was generated

Comment: seems nice, but isnt full reporting on? with `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);`?

Comment: If it is, you should be getting a "headers already sent" warning written to the file.... and I don't see it in the file

Comment: Check for a BOM heading in your script file as well, ensure that it is saved as "UTF-8 __without BOM__"

Comment: added `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` even added `charset=utf-8` to the headers .. nothing .. is there any other way to save this excel file?

Comment: Your output buffering is probably swallowing the warning. Comment out the `ob_start();` and `ob_end_clean();` lines, then re-run and check for those warnings in the file using a text editor

Comment: same thing, and i just found out that all the pages in my cakephp app have a blank line at the beginning ...

Comment: Well that blank line at the beginning is certainly going to be the cause of the problem, though I still don't understand why full error logging isn't generating that warning